# Which component does dynamic linking?

Tags: dll, linker, operating-system, dynamic-linking

My question is equivalent to: "What exactly is Dynamic Linker? Which part of an OS does it belong to?".
I know that dynamic linking is done by a component called "dynamic linker" which is also a part of an Operating System. I was wodering if this component can be seen as a part of

- Linker (the same that does static linking),
- Loader,
- RunTime Environment (given that dynamic linking is done while program is "running")
- or is it completely different component?

Answer (score 1):

> I know that dynamic linking is done by a component called "dynamic linker" which is also a part of an Operating System.

The dynamic linker is a part of the OS only on *some* OSes, namely Windows.

On UNIX, it is *not* part of the OS, but rather a part of `libc`, and you could have multiple dynamic linkers on a single system.

The dynamic loader is part of the runtime environment. It closely cooperates with the static linker (which must prepare the data structures used by the loader) and the OS kernel, but is never a "part" of either.